# How to get file image url in graphql for a Metaobject

Tags: graphql, shopify

I am using StoreFront API call to get Metaobject entries. One of the fields is of a type file (image). When I call the GRAPHQL with below call. I am getting all the fields but getting image as gid reference. I wan actual cdn url which I am not able to find anywhere in the shopify documentation. Below is the query which I have tried.

**What I want to achieve is to get image/file url but it is returning gid reference**.

**POST**: https://alg-demo-store.myshopify.com/api/unstable/graphql.json

```
query {
  metaobjects(type: "where_to_buy" first: 10) { 
      
      nodes{
          id
          handle
          country: field(key: "country") { value }  
          file: field(key: "company_logo") { value }  
         reference{
             ... on MediaImage {
            image {
              url
            }
          }
         } 
      }
  }
}
```

Also I have tried below code to retrive url of image. But not returning null.

```
query {
  metaobjects(type: "where_to_buy" first: 10) { 
      
      nodes{
          id
          handle
          country: field(key: "country") { value }            
          file: field(key: "company_logo") { reference {
        ... on MediaImage {
           previewImage {
            originalSrc
            url
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
  }
}



Result:

{
    "data": {
        "metaobjects": {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": "gid://shopify/Metaobject/14555742524",
                    "handle": "API-DE",
                    "country": {
                        "value": "Germany"
                    },
                    "file": {
                        "reference": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "gid://shopify/Metaobject/14556594492",
                    "handle": "cos-computers",
                    "country": {
                        "value": "Germany"
                    },
                    "file": {
                        "reference": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```